# TrustedInstaller.exe Continuous Memory Consumption

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2008-r2

I’m having an odd issue with TrustedInstaller.exe on Windows 2008 R2, and no it is not runaway CPU usage.  TrustedInstaller.exe runs continuously and steadily uses more memory.  I have let it run for 3 days straight hoping it would work through its issue, but I ended up stopping the process after it hit 700mb.  It started the day after installing .Net 4.5.2, rebooting and then installing the May Rollup for .Net KB4019112 and rebooting.  I have another Win 2008 R2, which did not have this issue.

When I look at the Instance in Process Explorer, there are 100+ unnamed Event Handles, several EtwRegistration Handels and several TpWorkerFactory Handels, if any of that helps.

I am able to run other windows installs, so it is still doing its job, just not letting go of memory.

I have ran SFC and it found no issues.

I have noticed though that there are 2k+ files in winsxs\Temp\PendingRenames dated from later in the day when this started.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that process stop after rebooting? Do you have any pending optional feature installation?

Comment: It Starts back up after reboot with the same behavior.  It will behave normally for about 5-10 min then just chewing up the memory.  Nothing is pending install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your assistance.  I was able to resolve the issue by running Disk Cleanup, choosing Cleanup system files, and checking the  Windows Update Cleanup category.  THis makes sense as the issue started after installing some updates.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know but check https://marc.durdin.net/2012/02/further-analysis-on-the-trustedinstaller-exe-memory-leaks/ for more details. I've noticed it can happen when someone has left server manager open (look for running mmc processes) as that can prevent trusted installer from shutting down. Kill them off and wait 10 mins and trusted installer shuts down.

Comment: I found this article and did some testing, but the service with the bloated memory persists even with no MMC running.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: link appears to be broken.